# Windows: Registry: Can't associate a file with a verb

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

RESTORED to original question as well as I could, 7/27/19 1:08 PM

I've created the following .reg file to add a shell verb 'Build PGL File' for .pgl files. The verb should run Firefox with a command line.

After double-clicking this .reg file, the keys and values are merged into the Registry. But right-clicking a .pgl file in File Manager shows a 'Build PGL File' verb that has no file association.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.pgl]
@="PGLFile"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\PGLFile]
@="PGL Document"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\PGLFile\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\PGLFile\shell\Build]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\PGLFile\shell\Build\command]
@="firefox.exe doit.php?%1%"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the registry, navigate to:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.pgl
```

and delete the `UserChoice` subkey.

Comment: No subkey. Deleted the .pgl key. Did not work. No effect.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to navigate to

```
http://localhost/springweb/springweb.php
```

when you right-click a .pgl file and then click on an item in the right-click menu that says for example : **Go to springweb**

This can be achieved as follows

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Start url]
"icon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\""
"MUIVerb"="Go to vbsedit.com"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\start url\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\" https://www.vbsedit.com"
```

In your case, **VBSFile** must then become **PGLFile**.

Search for it under **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT**

`https://www.vbsedit.com` must then become `http://localhost/springweb/springweb.php`

this will be opened in IE

**MUIVerb** will display the name **Go to springweb** in the context menu.

"MUIVerb"="Go to vbsedit.com" change **Go to vbsedit.com** to **Go to springweb**, or whatever you want.

If you leave out **"MUIVerb"="Go to springweb"**

then **Start url** will be displayed.

Comment: Yay! This opened IE to the path nicely (I will have to change it to open FireFox). Amazing magic, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, with the help of Dr RedAnt .

Here is the correct solution, with backslashes doubled (stupid .reg file format):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pgl]
@="PGLFile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PGLFile\Shell\Start url]
"icon"="\"C:\\Web\\springweb\\SpringWebLogo.png\""
"MUIVerb"="Build PGL File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PGLFile\Shell\Start url\Command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\" http://localhost/springweb/springweb.php"
```

Comment: I can't get changes to the Command subkey to be seen by Explorer. Does it have a cache?